# Norm of summation of vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, metric-tensor

If we have a vector $\partial_v$ and we want o find its norm, we easily say (According to the given metric) that the norm of that vector is:$ g^{vv}\partial_v\partial_v$.

My question what if we have a vector that is combination of 2 vectors like: $\partial_v + a\partial_x$ where $a$ is any constant.. How do we find its norm?

Comment: What hinders you to do the same? Also, $\partial_\mu$ is a *vector*, not a covector, since the covector space is spanned by the differentials $\mathrm{d}x^\mu$, which are the *duals* of the derivatives $\partial_\mu$.

Comment: Comments to the question (v1): Firstly, the question seems to confuse vectors and covectors. Secondly, $g^{vv}\partial_v\partial_v$ is not a norm.

Comment: Sorry I will edit that.. My bad.

Comment: @ACuriousMind you mean that the norm would be: $g^{vv}\partial_v\partial_v + a g^{xx}\partial_x\partial_x$?

Comment: Is that what you meant? To me that meant as if I am finding the norm of the components of the vector and not the vector itself. @ACuriousMind

Answer (score 3):

A general vector is written as $v = v^\mu \partial_\mu$. Its norm is defined as

$$ g(v,v) = g_{\mu\nu}(\mathrm{d}x^\mu \otimes \mathrm{d}x^\nu)(v^\mu\partial_\mu,v^\nu\partial_\nu) = g_{\mu\nu}v^\mu v^\nu (\mathrm{d}x^\mu \otimes \mathrm{d}x^\nu)(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu) = g_{\mu\nu}v^\mu v^\nu$$

where we have used linearity of the duals and $\mathrm{d}x^\mu(\partial_\nu) = \delta^\mu_\nu$ by definition.

Comment: Thank you but I am not familiar with the notation.. So is what I wrote in the comment above correct? And does it fit the general equation you wrote in the answer?

Comment: @beyondtheory: No, what you say in the comment is not correct. Also, this notation is absolutely standard - it uses the [Einstein summation convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_summation), and that the metric $g(\dot{},\dot{})$ is a rank $(0,2)$-tensor, i.e. takes two vectors as input to produce a scalar.